# Access SQL using IN where record must satisfy all values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a join statement, like this:

```
SELECT 
distinct(p.id), p.id, p.first_name as [First Name], p.last_name as [Last Name] 
FROM  tbl_person as p , 
tbl_person_languages as pl
WHERE  
pl.person_id = p.id  AND 
pl.language_id in (12,14,...)
```

but this returns all records.  I would like to pull back the distinct record of an individual that has all values of pl.language_id, not just one or more values.  I should note, the values in the IN statement may have 1 or more values

Any ideas on how to do this?  I've tried changing the IN statement to something like this:

```
 WHERE  
    pl.person_id = p.id  AND 
    pl.language_id =12 AND
    pl.language_id = 14
```

but this returns nothing.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `group by` and  `count`:

```
SELECT 
     p.id, p.first_name as [First Name], p.last_name as [Last Name] 
FROM  tbl_person as p , 
tbl_person_languages as pl
WHERE  
pl.person_id = p.id  AND 
pl.language_id in (12,14,...)
GROUP BY p.id, p.first_name, p.last_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pl.language_id) = 2   -- 12 and 14
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have tried this, but get an error:  Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression 'COUNT (DISTINCT pl.language_id) =2'.  Thoughts?

Comment: Maybe `access` doesnt accept the `DISTINCT` inside `COUNT`, try without it. That is only a problem if a person can have the same lenguaje multiple time and alter the count result. But probably in your case doesnt matter?

Comment: Yeah, when I got rid of the Distinct keyword, this worked fine.  This should works, as they cannot have multiple language_id that are the same

Comment: btw, Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: Yes, normally I would use the JOIN statement, but I'm generating the SQL statement via code, which must iterate over various fields to build the statement.

Comment: well, if you can add `where` in the code you can add `ON`. remember leave upvote.